# Regex matching 0 or more instances of key words, in any order

Tags: regex

I'm decent with regexes but stumped here.  I'm having trouble with **group 2**, below. However, I think this should be fairly easy for a regex guru...

### Problem

I'm trying to match `zero or more instances of a set of keywords, in any order`

---

*[Update: For future reference]

The simplest solution (derived from [black panda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261887/black-panda)'s response) is:*
`((keyword1 | keyword2 | keyword3 )*)`

*note: the space after each word is essential!*

*In my case, this translated into:*
`((static |final )*)`

*this is is the bare-bones, simplest answer.  The better, more performant approach is in [black panda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261887/black-panda)'s response, below. It allows for any amount of whitespace and is faster for a RE engine to process.*

---

### Input

I need to split the following input into very specific groups.

*Note: the numbers are not part of the input. That is, each input line starts with the letter p.*

1. public static final int ONE = 1;
2. public final static int TWO = 2;
3. public final int THREE = 3;
4. public static int FOUR = 4;
5. private int FIVE = 5;

### Groups

I need to break the input into match groups such that

group 1 = public or private or protected
**group 2 = 0 or more instances of "static" or "final"**      ***<-- group I'm struggling with***
group 3 = data type
group 4 = variable name
group 5 = value

### Group 2 Details

Given the input above, group 2 would be as follows:

1. static final
2. final static
3. final
4. static
5. [empty string]

### Failed Solutions

this is the regex I came up with and id doesn't work for group 2:

```
^.*(public|private|protected)\s+(static\s+|final\s+)*\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s*(;|=)(.*)$
```

for group 2, I've tried:

- (static\s+|final\s+)*
- (static|final)*\s+
- (static |final )*
- (static\ |final\ )*

### Summary

What should be the regular expression for "group 2" that matches one or more instances of the words "static" or "final".  A proper solution would be expandable to match any subset of any words such as [static, final, transient, volatile].

Comment: to the person who flagged this question as "too localized" : matching zero or more instances of a subset of words is extremely powerful and generically useful.  In fact, if I find an answer to this, I can think of dozens of other places to use it.

Comment: what is the end result your trying to accomplish?  What are you trying to extract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you grab everything inbetween, and make sure groups 3 and greater exist?

group 2 = `((?:(?:static|final|transient|volatile)\s+)*)`

Comment: this worked perfectly for me and is fairly elegant and decently performant (didn't take a long time).  I'll test this a bit more but I think this is what I need.

Comment: The above is not correct though, it will match "final final" "final static final" etc etc

Comment: tested this a bit more and it looks good but I don't understand it.  Why do we need the second non-capturing group?  At a high level, how does this work?

Comment: @gmale the outer non-capturing group grabs all of the combinations of the words static, final, transient, and volatile that exist, including the space that separates the word from the next word coming up. The inner non-capturing group grabs a single word.

Comment: The outer-most group captures the whole shebang.

Comment: Great explanation. One question: why do we need the non-capturing groups at all? Meaning, why doesn't this work when we remove the ?: parts?  Is it that... we want it to match each word, but not consume them. Then we want it to match multiple instances of each word and not consume them?  Then the outer-most group does the final consumption of the whole shebang?

Comment: It does work without the ?: parts; i just generally add them when i don't want the regular expression engine to keep track of the unnecessary captures. It's more efficient for the RE engine.

Comment: Thanks, gmale :)  @refp My response to your comment still stands. Your expression still fails a certain sequence of the declaration statement, but that's ok, because the OP never asked that it be complicated enough to match exactly what a compiler would. I accept your -1 as long as the OP is satisfied. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

while(<DATA>) {
    my @l = $_ =~ /^\s*(public|private|protected)\s+((?:static\s+|final\s+)*)\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)(?:\s+=\s*(.*))?\s*;\s*$/;
    dump@l;
}

__DATA__
public static final int ONE = 1;
public final static int TWO = 2;
public final int THREE = 3;
public static int FOUR = 4;
private int FIVE = 5;
```

**output:**

```
("public", "static final", "int", "ONE", 1)
("public", "final static", "int", "TWO", 2)
("public", "final", "int", "THREE", 3)
("public", "static", "int", "FOUR", 4)
("private", "", "int", "FIVE", 5)
```

Comment: Note: this will match "static static" and "final static final".

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
^(?!.*\bstatic\s+static\b)(?!.*\bfinal\s+final\b).*(public|private|protected)\s+(static\s+|final\s+)?(static\s+|final\s+)?(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*(;|=.*)$
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/j2uVujbYSn)

Answer (score 0):

This matches zero or more instances of the words "static" or "final":

```
(static|final)*
```

As you can see from these perl snippets:

```
perl -e '$_ = "static final"; print $1 if /(static|final)*/;'  # prints "static"
perl -e '$_ = ""; print "matched" if /(static|final)*/;'
```

If your matches aren't working, then the problem is likely elsewhere

Comment: not exactly.  in your example, instead of matching "static final", you are matching "static".  Which means, if I substitute (static|final) in the longer regex above, it will match inputs 3-5 but not match inputs 1 and 2...

Comment: Ah, I see. @refp's solution would be the way to go then.